# Vertex operator algebras and modular tensor categories

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, conformal-field-theory, fusion-categories, vertex-algebras, modular-tensor-categories

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a vertex operator algebra (VOA), and let $\mathcal{C}=Rep(\mathcal{V})$ be the tensor category of (ususal) $\mathcal{V}$-modules. It is a well-known open-problem whether every modular tensor category is of this form. But in general, $\mathcal{C}$ is not finite (and not semisimple) so is not modular in the usual sense.

Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite semisimple tensor category (i.e. a fusion category), then:

**Question**: Is $\mathcal{C}$ a modular tensor category?

If it helps, let us assume also that $\mathcal{C}$ is unitary.

Comment: I'm confused about setting in the question. Is $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathcal{V})$ larger than the one Huang (and Huang-Lepowsky) are working with?